# Async json parsing- What am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, json

I have been trying to work on an app in which after clicking ,a new activity opens up and loads the data from the url.
Here is the new activity code

ProgressDialog dialog;

```
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Processing");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            String url = " http://www.trailermag.com/tsappapis/?request=featuredAdList";
            JSONArray trailersJSON = jsonObject.getJSONArray(url);
            for (int i = 0; i < trailersJSON.length(); i++) {
                Trail aTrail = new Trail();
                JSONObject contactObject = trailersJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                aTrail.id = contactObject.getString(V_Id);
                aTrail.image = contactObject.getString(V_Image);
                aTrail.title = contactObject.getString(V_Title);
                aTrail.price = contactObject.getString(V_Price);
                webData.add(aTrail);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            System.out.println("IN POST EXE");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it is better to share your JSON so that i can give you the solution....

Comment: What is the error you are facing with?

Comment: Am getting a blank white screen as soon as i go from first activity to the second.
Let me attach the complete JSON code.

Comment: @Amaresh here is the JSON:-

[
  {
    "id": "71785",
    "image": "71785.jpg",
    "title": "Factory Direct 2016 8x25+5 14k",
    "price": "6495"
  },
  {
    "id": "71784",
    "image": "71784.jpg",
    "title": "Factory Direct 2016 7x14 16k",
    "price": "5695"
  },

Comment: 1) Whats exactly the problem you're facing and 2) what jsonObject.getJSONArray(url); is supposed to do? Load the json text from URL? pls. post also the code of JSONObject.getJSONArray.

Comment: pls desribe your prblem clearly

Answer (score -1):

Once try and replace this code with your code this will work and i have tested it.

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < mJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String idStr = mJsonObject.getString("id");
                    String imageStr = mJsonObject.getString("image");
                    String titleStr = mJsonObject.getString("title");
                    String priceStr = mJsonObject.getString("price");
                }
```

Happeee...Programming....